# android extend class with native methods

Tags: android, inheritance, native, extends

I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940502/is-it-possible-to-override-a-native-method-in-a-java-class-in-android-dalvik) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744315/override-native-methods-in-android) that you cannot override native methods in android, but I was wondering if I can have a class declaring some native methods, and then extend it with another class declaring some additional native methods.

My situation is as follows:

```
public class A{
    public native int aMethod();
}

public class B extends A{
    public native int bMethod();

    static {
        try{
            System.loadLibrary("MyNativeLibraryWithBothaMethodAndbMethod");
        }
        catch (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError e){
            System.out.println (e);
        }
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private B bClass;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        bClass = new B();
        bClass.aMethod();//Working fine
        bClass.bMethod();//UnsatisfiedLinkError

    }
}
```

The library is loaded without problems, and the first method is called, but not the second.

If I move the bMethod from B to A, everything works fine.

Moving the System.loadlibrary() from B to A seems to have no effect.

Is it possible to extend A class with additional native methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I just found the solution.
The problem was in the .cpp file:

I edited the `MyNativeLibraryWithBothaMethodAndbMethod` file:

```
#include "my_package_name_A.h"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_my_package_name_A_aMethod( ... ){ ... }
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_my_package_name_A_bMethod( ... ){ ... }
```

with

```
#include "my_package_name_A.h"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_my_package_name_A_aMethod( ... ){ ... }
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_my_package_name_B_bMethod( ... ){ ... }
```

Note the "*B*" in the second signature.